# Unfair coin flip probability calculation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose I have an unfair coin, and the probability of flipping a head (`H`) is `p`, probability of flipping a tail (`T`) is `(1-p)`.

If I flip the coin 6 times, I'm wondering if the probability of `HTT???`, and the probability of `THT???`, and the probability of `TTH???` are the same? Suppose each flip is independent, and `?` means "do not care if head or tail".

I calculated they are the same, but I ask here to get advice from the experts whether my calculation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all the three events are independent. The cumulative law gives you:

t * h * t = h * t * t = t * t * h

If you enter values, you will get:

0.3 * 0.7 * 0.3 = 0.7 * 0.3 * 0.3 = 0.3 * 0.3 * 0.7 = 0.063

Edit:
It does not matter what the first three times are because of the law of conditional probability:

$P(A \bigcap B) = P(A) * P(B) \Leftrightarrow P(A) = \frac{P(A)P(B)} {P(B)} = \frac{P(A)\bigcap P(B)} {P(B)} = P(A|B)$

You can also take an example. All equations have the same product.

**0.3 * 0.7 * 0.3** * 0.3$^ 3$ = 0.001701

**0.7 * 0.3 * 0.3** * 0.3$^ 3$ = 0.001701

**0.3 * 0.3 * 0.7** * 0.3$^ 3$ = 0.001701

The last could be any combination of head and tail. 0.3$^ 3$ is just an example, but it works out equally if one or two or three of the variables is 0.7.

Comment: Thanks Ferdi, vote up for your reply. But I mean flip 6 times, other than flip 3 times as you mentioned in your reply. And I do not care the last 3 time result. Maybe you can read my question again. Let me know if anything unclear. :)

Comment: Thanks Ferdi, two more comments, I think I mean for the first time times, it is HTT, THT or TTH, the last 3 times does not mater (total 6 times flip), so I think it should be `0.3 * 0.7 * 0.3 * 0.3 ^ 3` other than `0.3 ^ 3 * 0.3 * 0.7 * 0.3`? The other comment is, not sure why you are using 0.3^3, the last 3 times could be any combinations of head and tail.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I edited my post once again. I just stood up, so I am still tired and not on the peak of my daily performance.

Comment: A further question, suppose I still flip 6 times, and I do not care first 3 flip results, and only care the last 3 flips results, for the 3 events, they are also of the same probability -- `???HTT`, `???THT` and `???TTH`? And their probability is the same as `HTT???`, `THT???` and `TTH???` (where I care first 3 flip results, and do not quite care last time flips)?

Comment: Hi Ferdi, if you could comment on my above question, it will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is positive.  To make the argument rigorous, you need to settle the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ for the experiment of "tossing an unfair coin for six times" first. Clearly, $\Omega$ is the set $\{H, T\}^6$, or equivalently (just for mathematical convenience, denoting "$H$" by $1$ and "$T$" by $0$),
\begin{align*}
\Omega = \{(\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots, \omega_6): \omega_i \in \{0, 1\}, i = 1, \ldots, 6\}. 
\end{align*}
It is easy to verify that $\Omega$ contains $2^6$ points, hence it is a finite sample space, thereby we can just let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of all subsets of $\Omega$.  Finally, the probability of seeing a $\omega_1\omega_2\cdots\omega_6$ sequence is
\begin{align*}
P(\{(\omega_1, \omega_2, \ldots, \omega_6)\}) = \prod_{i = 1}^6p^{\omega_i}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_i}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}

After this stage is set up, to calculate the probability of your interest, it is just a matter of expressing your event as a disjoint union of atom events $\{(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_6)\}$ then summing probabilities like $\eqref{1}$ by the third axiom of probability. For example, the event `HTT???` (denoted it by $A_1$) can be written as
\begin{align*}
A_1 = \bigcup_{\omega_4 \in \{0, 1\}}\bigcup_{\omega_5 \in \{0, 1\}}\bigcup_{\omega_6 \in \{0, 1\}}\{(1, 0, 0, \omega_4, \omega_5, \omega_6)\}, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
and by $\eqref{1}$, we have
\begin{align*}
P(\{(1, 0, 0, \omega_4, \omega_5, \omega_6)\}) = p(1 - p)^2\prod_{i = 4}^6p^{\omega_i}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_i}. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
Since all the sets in the union of $\eqref{2}$ are disjoint, $\eqref{3}$ then yields
\begin{align*}
P(A_1) = \sum_{\omega_4 \in \{0, 1\}}\sum_{\omega_5 \in \{0, 1\}}\sum_{\omega_6 \in \{0, 1\}}p(1 - p)^2\prod_{i = 4}^6p^{\omega_i}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_i} = p(1 - p)^2.
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
The details of evaluating the triple-sum in $\eqref{4}$ is spelled out as follows:
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{\omega_4 \in \{0, 1\}}\sum_{\omega_5 \in \{0, 1\}}\sum_{\omega_6 \in \{0, 1\}}p(1 - p)^2\prod_{i = 4}^6p^{\omega_i}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_i} \\
=& p(1 - p)^2\sum_{\omega_4 \in \{0, 1\}}\sum_{\omega_5 \in \{0, 1\}}p^{\omega_4}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_4}p^{\omega_5}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_5}(p + 1 - p) \\
=& p(1 - p)^2\sum_{\omega_4 \in \{0, 1\}}p^{\omega_4}(1 - p)^{1 - \omega_4}(p + 1 - p) \\
=& p(1 - p)^2(p + 1 - p) \\
=& p(1 - p)^2. 
\end{align*}
There is also an less verbose, probabilistic argument: you may just view $\{(\omega_4, \omega_5, \omega_6): \omega_i \in \{0, 1\}\}$ as the sample space of tossing the same coin for three times, and the triple sum is just the probability of getting all the outcomes of this experiment, which of course equals to $1$.

In the same manner, you should be able to verify that $P(THT???) = P(TTH???) = p(1 - p)^2$. More generally, can you see that when we change "6" to any $n$ such that $n > 3$, the probabilities of events $HTT\underbrace{???\cdots???}_{n - 3\text{ times}}$, $THT\underbrace{???\cdots???}_{n - 3\text{ times}}$, $TTH\underbrace{???\cdots???}_{n - 3\text{ times}}$ are still all $p(1 - p)^2$?